# avr codevision issue getting acknowledge or TX_DS flag in nRF24L01+ MODULE

Tags: module, avr, atmel

I am trying to communicate using two [nRF24L01](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/2.4GHz-RF/nRF24L01) radio modules connected to atmega8s over spi.

All I can do is to write some register of the nRF, but no data can be sent. When I read the radio status register it returns decimal 14 or sometimes 0 or sometimes decimal 30.

Here is my atmega8 code:

```
#include <mega8.h>
#include <C:\cvavr\BIN\nRF24L01\nrf24l012.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcf8576d.h>

#define    _CH 1            // Channel 0..125
#define    _Address_Width 5    // 3..5
#define _Buffer_Size 32 // 1..32


// Declare your global variables here
unsigned char global_var=0;

void NRF24L01_Receive(char Buf[_Buffer_Size]) {
    NRF24L01_CE_HIGH;
    delay_us(130);

    while ((NRF24L01_Get_Status() & _RX_DR) != _RX_DR);

    NRF24L01_CE_LOW;

    NRF24L01_Read_RX_Buf(Buf, _Buffer_Size);
    NRF24L01_Clear_Interrupts();
}


void NRF24L01_Send(char* Buf) {
    NRF24L01_Write_TX_Buf(Buf, _Buffer_Size);

    NRF24L01_RF_TX();

    while ((NRF24L01_Get_Status() & _TX_DS) != _TX_DS) ;

    NRF24L01_Clear_Interrupts();

}

// External Interrupt 1 service routine
interrupt [EXT_INT1] void ext_int1_isr(void)
{
    char buffer[32];
    char state = NRF24L01_Get_Status(); 
    lcd_erase();
    lcd_printf("INT ");
    lcd_print(state);
    if(state==0) NRF24L01_Read_RX_Buf(buffer,32);
    lcd_print(buffer[0]); 
    delay_ms(100);

    NRF24L01_Clear_Interrupts();
}

// SPI interrupt service routine
interrupt [SPI_STC] void spi_isr(void)
{



}


void main(void)
{
    // Declare your local variables here
    char i;
    unsigned char bffr[5];
    unsigned char Buf[_Buffer_Size];
    unsigned char Data[5]={3,9,5,8,4};
    unsigned char Address_p0[_Address_Width] = { 0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xe1  }; 
    unsigned char Address_p1[_Address_Width] = { 0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xf0,0xd2  }; 
    unsigned char Address_p2[1]={0xc3};
    unsigned char Address_p3[1]={0xc4};
    unsigned char Address_p4[1]={0xc5};
    unsigned char Address_p5[1]={0xc6};
    spi_int1_init();    
    TWI_init_master();

    delay_ms(300); 
    lcd_erase();
    lcd_printf("start");
    delay_ms(1200);

    NRF24L01_Init(_TX_MODE, _CH, _1Mbps, Address_p0, _Address_Width, _Buffer_Size);
    NRF24L01_WriteReg(W_REGISTER | EN_RXADDR,0x03);
    NRF24L01_Set_RX_Pipe (0,Address_p0,_Address_Width, _Buffer_Size);
    NRF24L01_Set_RX_Pipe (1,Address_p1,_Address_Width, _Buffer_Size); 
    NRF24L01_Set_TX_Address(Address_p0,_Address_Width);
    NRF24L01_Set_RX_Pipe (2,Address_p2,1,0); 
    NRF24L01_Set_RX_Pipe (3,Address_p3,1,0);
    NRF24L01_Set_RX_Pipe (4,Address_p4,1,0);
    NRF24L01_Set_RX_Pipe (5,Address_p5,1,0);
    NRF24L01_WriteReg(W_REGISTER | EN_AA,0X3F);
    NRF24L01_WriteReg(W_REGISTER | EN_RXADDR,0x03);
    NRF24L01_WriteReg(W_REGISTER | RF_CH, 0x0c); 
    NRF24L01_WriteReg(W_REGISTER | RF_SETUP,0X03);
    NRF24L01_WriteReg(W_REGISTER | CONFIG,0X0E);
    NRF24L01_WriteReg(W_REGISTER | SETUP_RETR,0X28);


    global_var = NRF24L01_Get_Status();
    //global_var=SPI(234);
    lcd_erase();
    lcd_print(global_var);
    delay_ms(1000);
    global_var = NRF24L01_ReadReg(CONFIG);
    lcd_erase();
    lcd_print(global_var);
    delay_ms(1000);

    lcd_erase();
    NRF24L01_ReadRegBuf(TX_ADDR,bffr,5);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        lcd_print(bffr[i]);
    delay_ms(1000);

    global_var = NRF24L01_ReadReg(FIFO_STATUS);
    lcd_erase();
    lcd_printf("ffo ");
    lcd_print(global_var);  
    delay_ms(1000);

    NRF24L01_Send(Data);  
    global_var = NRF24L01_Get_Status();
    lcd_erase();
    lcd_print(global_var);  
    delay_ms(1000);

    global_var = NRF24L01_ReadReg(FIFO_STATUS);
    lcd_erase();
    lcd_printf("mioh ");
    lcd_print(global_var);  
    delay_ms(1000);

    while (1);
}
```

and here is my nrf24l012.h

```
#include <delay.h>
#include <C:\cvavr\BIN\nRF24L01\nrf24l011.h>  


/*
 * SPI pins:
 * MOSI: DDB3
 * MISO: DDB4
 * SCK : DDB5
 * CSN : DDB2
 * CE   : DDB1
 */
 void spi_int1_init(void){
 // Input/Output Ports initialization
// Port B initialization
// Function: Bit7=In Bit6=In Bit5=Out Bit4=In Bit3=Out Bit2=Out Bit1=In Bit0=In 
DDRB=(0<<DDB7) | (0<<DDB6) | (1<<DDB5) | (0<<DDB4) | (1<<DDB3) | (1<<DDB2) | (1<<DDB1) | (0<<DDB0);
// State: Bit7=T Bit6=T Bit5=0 Bit4=T Bit3=0 Bit2=0 Bit1=T Bit0=T 
PORTB=(0<<PORTB7) | (0<<PORTB6) | (0<<PORTB5) | (0<<PORTB4) | (0<<PORTB3) | (0<<PORTB2) | (0<<PORTB1) | (0<<PORTB0);


// External Interrupt(s) initialization
// INT0: Off
// INT1: On
// INT1 Mode: Falling Edge
GICR|=(1<<INT1) | (0<<INT0);
MCUCR=(1<<ISC11) | (0<<ISC10) | (0<<ISC01) | (0<<ISC00);
GIFR=(1<<INTF1) | (0<<INTF0);


// SPI initialization
// SPI Type: Master
// SPI Clock Rate: 2000.000 kHz
// SPI Clock Phase: Cycle Start
// SPI Clock Polarity: Low
// SPI Data Order: MSB First
SPCR=(1<<SPIE) | (1<<SPE) | (0<<DORD) | (1<<MSTR) | (0<<CPOL) | (0<<CPHA) | (0<<SPR1) | (0<<SPR0);
SPSR=(0<<SPI2X);

// Clear the SPI interrupt flag
#asm
    in   r30,spsr
    in   r30,spdr
#endasm


// Global enable interrupts
#asm("sei")
 }

//Function to send and receive data for both master and slave
unsigned char SPI(unsigned char data)
{

    // Load data into the buffer
    SPDR = data;

    //Wait until transmission complete
    while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF) )); 

    SPSR = (1<<SPIF);      
    // Return received data
    return(SPDR);
}



/* CE is set to output */

#define NRF24L01_CE_OUT       DDRB  |= (1<<DDB1) ;
#define NRF24L01_CE_HIGH      PORTB |= (1<<DDB1) ;
#define NRF24L01_CE_LOW       PORTB &= ~(1<<DDB1);
#define NRF24L01_CSN_HIGH     PORTB |= (1<<DDB2) ;
#define NRF24L01_CSN_LOW      PORTB &= ~(1<<DDB2);

/**
 Read a register

 @param Reg Register to read

 @return Registry Value
*/
char NRF24L01_ReadReg(char Reg) {
    char Result;

    NRF24L01_CSN_LOW;
    SPI(Reg);
    Result = SPI(NOP);    // "NOP"  in here just roles as a dummy data byte  nothing more.
    NRF24L01_CSN_HIGH;

    return Result;
}

/**
 Returns the STATUS register and then modify a register

 @param Reg Register to change
 @param Value New value

 @return STATUS Register
*/
char NRF24L01_WriteReg(char Reg, char Value) {
    char Result;

    NRF24L01_CSN_LOW;
    Result = SPI(Reg);
    SPI(Value);
    NRF24L01_CSN_HIGH;

    return Result;
}

/**
 Returns the STATUS register and then read "n" registers

 @param Reg Register to read
 @param Buf Pointer to a buffer
 @param Size Buffer Size

 @return STATUS Register
*/
char NRF24L01_ReadRegBuf(char Reg, char *Buf, int Size) {
    int i;
    char Result;

    NRF24L01_CSN_LOW;
    Result = SPI(Reg);

    for (i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
        Buf[i] = SPI(NOP);
    }

    NRF24L01_CSN_HIGH;

    return Result;
}

/**
 Returns the STATUS register and then write "n" registers

 @param Reg Registers to change
 @param Buf Pointer to a buffer
 @param Size Buffer Size

 @return STATUS Register
*/
char NRF24L01_WriteRegBuf(char Reg, char *Buf, int Size) {
    int i;
    char Result;

    NRF24L01_CSN_LOW;
    Result = SPI(Reg);

    for (i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
        SPI(Buf[i]);
    }
    NRF24L01_CSN_HIGH;

    return Result;
}

/**
 Returns the STATUS register

 @return STATUS Register
*/
char NRF24L01_Get_Status(void) {
    char Result;

    NRF24L01_CSN_LOW;
    Result = SPI(NOP);
    NRF24L01_CSN_HIGH;

    return Result;
}

/**
 Returns the carrier signal in RX mode (high when detected)

 @return CD
*/
char NRF24L01_Get_CD(void) {
    return (NRF24L01_ReadReg(CD) & 1);
}

/**
 Select power mode

 @param Mode = _POWER_DOWN, _POWER_UP

 @see _POWER_DOWN
 @see _POWER_UP

*/
void NRF24L01_Set_Power(char Mode) {
    char Result;

    Result = NRF24L01_ReadReg(CONFIG) & 0b01111101; // Read Conf. Reg. AND Clear bit 1 (PWR_UP) and 7 (Reserved)
    NRF24L01_WriteReg(W_REGISTER | CONFIG, Result | Mode);
}

/**
 Select the radio channel

 @param CH = 0..125

*/
void NRF24L01_Set_CH(char CH) {
    NRF24L01_WriteReg(W_REGISTER | RF_CH, (CH & 0b01111111)); // Clear bit 8
}

/**
 Select Enhanced ShockBurst ON/OFF

 Disable this functionality to be compatible with nRF2401

 @param Mode = _ShockBurst_ON, _ShockBurst_OFF

 @see _ShockBurst_ON
 @see _ShockBurst_OFF

*/
void NRF24L01_Set_ShockBurst(char Mode) {
    NRF24L01_WriteReg(W_REGISTER | SETUP_RETR, Mode);
    NRF24L01_WriteReg(W_REGISTER | EN_AA, Mode);
}

/**
 Select the address width

 @param Width = 3..5
*/
void NRF24L01_Set_Address_Width(char Width) {
    NRF24L01_WriteReg(W_REGISTER | SETUP_AW, (Width - 2));  //  orginal was (Width & 3) -2)  but is incorrect
}

/**
 Select mode receiver or transmitter

 @param Device_Mode = _TX_MODE, _RX_MODE

 @see _TX_MODE
 @see _RX_MODE
*/
void NRF24L01_Set_Device_Mode(char Device_Mode) {
    char Result;

    Result = NRF24L01_ReadReg(CONFIG) & 0b01111110; // Read Conf. Reg. AND Clear bit 0 (PRIM_RX) and 7 (Reserved)
    NRF24L01_WriteReg(W_REGISTER | CONFIG, Result | Device_Mode);
}

/**
 Enables and configures the pipe receiving the data

 @param PipeNum Number of pipe
 @param Address Address
 @param AddressSize Address size
 @param PayloadSize Buffer size, data receiver

*/
void NRF24L01_Set_RX_Pipe(char PipeNum, char *Address, int AddressSize, char PayloadSize) {
    char Result;

    Result = NRF24L01_ReadReg(EN_RXADDR);
    NRF24L01_WriteReg(W_REGISTER | EN_RXADDR, Result | (1 << PipeNum));

    NRF24L01_WriteReg(W_REGISTER | (RX_PW_P0 + PipeNum), PayloadSize);
    NRF24L01_WriteRegBuf(W_REGISTER | (RX_ADDR_P0 + PipeNum), Address, AddressSize);
}

/**
 Disable all pipes
*/
void NRF24L01_Disable_All_Pipes(void) {
    NRF24L01_WriteReg(W_REGISTER | EN_RXADDR, 0);
}


/** Returns the STATUS register and then clear all interrupts
 *
 * @return STATUS Register
 */
char NRF24L01_Clear_Interrupts(void) {
    return NRF24L01_WriteReg(W_REGISTER | STATUS, _RX_DR | _TX_DS | _MAX_RT);
}

/**
 Sets the direction of transmission

 @param Address Address
 @param Size Address size 3..5

*/
void NRF24L01_Set_TX_Address(char *Address, int Size) {
    NRF24L01_WriteRegBuf(W_REGISTER | TX_ADDR, Address, Size);
}

/**
 Empty the transmit buffer

*/
void NRF24L01_Flush_TX(void) {
    NRF24L01_CSN_LOW;
    SPI(FLUSH_TX);
    NRF24L01_CSN_HIGH;
}

/**
 Empty the receive buffer
*/
void NRF24L01_Flush_RX(void) {
    NRF24L01_CSN_LOW;
    SPI(FLUSH_RX);
    NRF24L01_CSN_HIGH;
}

/**
 Initializes the device
 @param Device_Mode = _TX_MODE, _RX_MODE
 @param CH = 0..125
 @param DataRate = _1Mbps, _2Mbps
 @param Address Address
 @param Address_Width Width direction: 3..5
 @param Size_Payload Data buffer size

 @see _TX_MODE
 @see _RX_MODE
 @see _1Mbps
 @see _2Mbps
*/
void NRF24L01_Init(char Device_Mode, char CH, char DataRate,
        char *Address, char Address_Width, char Size_Payload) {

    NRF24L01_CE_OUT; // Set Port DIR out

    // Enable Enhanced ShockBurst....._ShockBurst_OFF
    NRF24L01_Set_ShockBurst(_ShockBurst_ON);

    // RF output power in TX mode = 0dBm (Max.)
    // Set LNA gain
    NRF24L01_WriteReg(W_REGISTER | RF_SETUP, 0b00000111 | DataRate);

    NRF24L01_Set_Address_Width(Address_Width);

    NRF24L01_Set_RX_Pipe(0, Address, Address_Width, Size_Payload);

    NRF24L01_Set_CH(CH);

    NRF24L01_Set_TX_Address(Address, Address_Width); // Set Transmit address

    // Bits 4..6: Reflect interrupts as active low on the IRQ pin
    // Bit 3: Enable CRC
    // Bit 2: CRC 1 Byte
    // Bit 1: Power Up
    NRF24L01_WriteReg(W_REGISTER | CONFIG, 0b00001010 | Device_Mode);

    delay_us(1500);
}

/**
 Turn on transmitter, and transmits the data loaded into the buffer
*/
void NRF24L01_RF_TX(void) {
    NRF24L01_CE_LOW;
    NRF24L01_CE_HIGH;
    delay_us(10);
    NRF24L01_CE_LOW;
}

/**
 Writes the buffer of data transmission

 @param Buf Buffer with data to send
 @param Size Buffer size

*/
void NRF24L01_Write_TX_Buf(char *Buf, int Size) {
    NRF24L01_WriteRegBuf(W_REGISTER | W_TX_PAYLOAD, Buf, Size);
}

/**
 Read the data reception buffer

 @param Buf Buffer with data received
 @param Size Buffer size

*/
void NRF24L01_Read_RX_Buf(char *Buf, int Size) {
    NRF24L01_ReadRegBuf(R_RX_PAYLOAD, Buf, Size);
}
```

i can not understand what is the problem..
please help me thanks?!

AND HERE IS nrf24l01+.h definition

```
/*
 * @author
 * Copyright (C) 2012 Luis R. Hilario http://www.luisdigital.com
 *
 */

// Bits

/**
 * Data Ready RX FIFO interrupt
 */
#define _RX_DR (1<<6)

/**
 * Data Sent TX FIFO interrupt
 */
#define _TX_DS (1<<5)

/**
 * Maximum number of TX retransmits interrupt
 */
#define _MAX_RT (1<<4)

/** Power Down mode
 *
 * Minimal current consumption, SPI can be activated
 *
 * @see NRF24L01_Set_Power(char Mode)
 */
#define _POWER_DOWN    0

/** Power Up mode
 *
 * Standby-I mode
 *
 * @see NRF24L01_Set_Power(char Mode)
 */
#define _POWER_UP    (1<<1)

/** Mode radio transmitter
 *
 * @see NRF24L01_Set_Device_Mode(char Device_Mode)
 * @see NRF24L01_Init(char Device_Mode, char CH, char DataRate,
        char *Address, char Address_Width, char Size_Payload)
 */
#define _TX_MODE    0

/** Mode radio receiver
 *
 * @see NRF24L01_Set_Device_Mode(char Device_Mode)
 * @see NRF24L01_Init(char Device_Mode, char CH, char DataRate,
        char *Address, char Address_Width, char Size_Payload)
 */
#define _RX_MODE    1

/**  Air data rate = 1 Mbps
 *
 *
 * @see NRF24L01_Init(char Device_Mode, char CH, char DataRate,
        char *Address, char Address_Width, char Size_Payload)
 */
#define    _1Mbps    0

/** Air data rate = 2 Mbps
 *
 * @see NRF24L01_Init(char Device_Mode, char CH, char DataRate,
        char *Address, char Address_Width, char Size_Payload)
 */
#define    _2Mbps    (1<<3)

/** Enable ShockBurst

 Automatic Retransmission (Up to 1 Re-Transmit on fail of AA)

 Auto Acknowledgment (data pipe 0)

 @see NRF24L01_Set_ShockBurst(char Mode)
 */
#define _ShockBurst_ON 1

/** Disable ShockBurst
 *
 @see NRF24L01_Set_ShockBurst(char Mode)
 */
#define _ShockBurst_OFF 0


// REGISTERS
#define CONFIG        0x00
#define EN_AA        0x01
#define EN_RXADDR    0x02
#define SETUP_AW    0x03
#define SETUP_RETR    0x04
#define RF_CH        0x05
#define RF_SETUP    0x06
#define STATUS        0x07
#define OBSERVE_TX    0x08
#define CD            0x09
#define RX_ADDR_P0    0x0A
#define RX_ADDR_P1    0x0B
#define RX_ADDR_P2    0x0C
#define RX_ADDR_P3    0x0D
#define RX_ADDR_P4    0x0E
#define RX_ADDR_P5    0x0F
#define TX_ADDR        0x10
#define RX_PW_P0    0x11
#define RX_PW_P1    0x12
#define RX_PW_P2    0x13
#define RX_PW_P3    0x14
#define RX_PW_P4    0x15
#define RX_PW_P5    0x16
#define FIFO_STATUS    0x17
#define DYNPD        0x1C
#define FEATURE        0x1D

// COMMANDS
#define R_REGISTER            0x00
#define W_REGISTER            0x20
#define R_RX_PAYLOAD        0x61
#define W_TX_PAYLOAD        0xA0
#define FLUSH_TX              0xE1
#define FLUSH_RX             0xE2
#define REUSE_TX_PL          0xE3
#define ACTIVATE            0x50
#define R_RX_PL_WID         0x60
#define W_ACK_PAYLOAD        0xA8
#define W_TX_PAYLOAD_NOACK    0x58
#define NOP                 0xFF

/*
 * SPI functions for NRF24L01
 */
char NRF24L01_ReadReg(char Reg);
char NRF24L01_WriteReg(char Reg, char Value);
char NRF24L01_ReadRegBuf(char Reg, char *Buf, int Size);
char NRF24L01_WriteRegBuf(char Reg, char *Buf, int Size);

/*
 * NRF24L01 functions
 */
char NRF24L01_Get_Status(void);
char NRF24L01_Get_CD(void);
void NRF24L01_Set_Power(char Mode);
void NRF24L01_Set_CH(char CH);
void NRF24L01_Set_ShockBurst(char Mode);
void NRF24L01_Set_Address_Width(char Width);
void NRF24L01_Set_Device_Mode(char Device_Mode);
void NRF24L01_Set_RX_Pipe(char PipeNum, char *Address, int AddressSize, char PayloadSize);
void NRF24L01_Disable_All_Pipes(void);
char NRF24L01_Clear_Interrupts(void);
void NRF24L01_Set_TX_Address(char *Address, int Size);
void NRF24L01_Flush_TX(void);
void NRF24L01_Flush_RX(void);
void NRF24L01_Init(char Device_Mode, char CH, char DataRate,
        char *Address, char Address_Width, char Size_Payload);
void NRF24L01_RF_TX(void);
void NRF24L01_Write_TX_Buf(char *Buf, int Size);
void NRF24L01_Read_RX_Buf(char *Buf, int Size);
```

Comment: The question is too long to except an answer. It should be as short as possible and still demonstrate the problem. Also, you need to say what you expect the code to do, and what it is doing instead.

Comment: It is bad style to have function definitions in a .h file. They should be in a .c file instead, but that is not causing your problem. It appears that some definitions that are needed to understand the status register are in nrf24l011.h. Please add that file to you question.

Comment: i added nrf24l011.h file..the code is going to transmit Data to another nrf module that is in rx mode and when an interrupt on IRQ pin accure it reads STATUS REGISTER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello friends succesfully i get it and i was able to send data over nrf24l01+ module to another nrf24l01+ module for this i used an ATMEGA16A as TX and an ATmega8a as RX(receiver) controller:
i used the code in this link written by some good people and it works perfectly but i need to change som i/o port to be compitable with Atmega8 for receiver module .
as i compare my last code with this one i understand that i changed rx and tx Adresses and in this code (works well) nothing is changed related to Adresses of module and left to its default values..
so my fault was manipulating adresses incorrectly..

here is the link to code works good..

UPDATE:  as i revisited my code to see whats problem i understand the whole problem was from nrf24l01.h file that declared a function misdingushly it sends W_TX_PAYLOAD ORing with W_REGISTER while such an adress is not exist in nrf so the whole process is got wrong..
error was in declaring :
'NRF24L01_Write_TX_Buf ' function
 in line:
NRF24L01_WriteRegBuf(W_REGISTER | W_TX_PAYLOAD, Buf, Size);
while this is wrong and must be Corrected as:

NRF24L01_WriteRegBuf(W_TX_PAYLOAD, Buf, Size);
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww

http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/nrf24l01-problem-communication-failure-cannot-even-read-registers-data-atmega16a